# MATLAB GUI: Update textbox when moving drawpoint

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I have a GUI where the user clicks a button to place a point (`drawpoint`). After placing the point, the Euclidean distance is calculated between it and a static point chosen prior.

I want to be able to move point created by the pushbutton; such that, after moving the point the Euclidean distance is recalculated and spit into a textbox.

I tried using `addlistener` (in the GUI_OpeningFcn postion) for the created point; however, I cannot figure out how to do this, as the handle doesn't exist until after the pushbutton is created.

Thus the issue: How can I dynamically perform a calculation and spit out the value upon moving a point? Below is the code for the pushbutton (which does what I want). But how can I recalculate after moving the point?

Perhaps, could this be down using `WindowbuttonDownFcn`? Again, just not sure how to incorporate this into the GUI.

```
% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton1.
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

h = findobj('Name', 'N');
Ndata = guidata(h);

axes(Ndata.axes1);

mypoint = drawpoint;

handles.distx = mypoint.Position(1);
handles.disty = mypoint.Position(2);

xp = Ndata.xpix;
yp = Ndata.ypix;
handles.poix = abs(double(handles.distx) - double(Ndata.ISOx))/str2double(xp.String);
handles.poiy = abs(double(handles.disty) - double(Ndata.ISOy))/str2double(yp.String);

handles.poi = sqrt(handles.poix^2 + handles.poiy^2)+1.3;

set(handles.edit1, 'Value', handles.poi);
set(handles.edit1, 'String', num2str(handles.poi));

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the event listener after creating the point.

1. Create the point:

   ```
   mypoint = drawpoint;
   ```
2. Add event listener only if not exist (add it to `handles`):

   ```
   %Add event listenr only if not exist
   if ~isfield(handles, 'el')
       handles.el = addlistener(mypoint, 'ROIMoved', @mypointmoved_Callback);
   end
   ```
3. Update the edit box in the callback function:

   ```
   function mypointmoved_Callback(src, eventData)
   handles = guidata(src.Parent); %Get the handles using the parent of the point (the axes).
   handles.distx = src.Position(1);
   handles.disty = src.Position(2);
   set(handles.edit1, 'String', num2str(handles.distx)); %Simplified version of your code.
   drawnow
   ```

Here is a simplified version of the code (I put some of your code in comments):

```
% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton1.
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
%h = findobj('Name', 'N');
%Ndata = guidata(h);

%axes(Ndata.axes1);
axes(handles.axes1);

mypoint = drawpoint;

%Add event listenr only if not exist
if ~isfield(handles, 'el')
    handles.el = addlistener(mypoint, 'ROIMoved', @mypointmoved_Callback);
end

handles.distx = mypoint.Position(1);
handles.disty = mypoint.Position(2);

% xp = Ndata.xpix;
% yp = Ndata.ypix;
% handles.poix = abs(double(handles.distx) - double(Ndata.ISOx))/str2double(xp.String);
% handles.poiy = abs(double(handles.disty) - double(Ndata.ISOy))/str2double(yp.String);

% handles.poi = sqrt(handles.poix^2 + handles.poiy^2)+1.3;

% set(handles.edit1, 'Value', handles.poi);
%set(handles.edit1, 'String', num2str(handles.poi));
set(handles.edit1, 'String', num2str(handles.distx));

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);


function mypointmoved_Callback(src, eventData)
handles = guidata(src.Parent); %Get the handles using the parent of the point (the axes).
handles.distx = src.Position(1);
handles.disty = src.Position(2);
set(handles.edit1, 'String', num2str(handles.distx));
drawnow
```

Comment: Ah, did not know it could work like that. I will give it a whirl today!

Comment: So, giving it a try (sorry if I am misunderstanding something), I cannot access the `handles` variables within the function `mypointmoved_Callback`. Thus I cannot perform the `set(handles.edit1, 'String', num2str(handles.distx));` line. How can I pass all of the handles etc. into the `mypointmoved_Callback`?

Comment: It doesn't seem to pass through all the handles variables (i.e. a text box within the figure, but not within the axes (if that makes sense). I am playing around with stuff, but still no avail.

Comment: The problem lies in the `mypoint` as the src. It does not contain the GUI variables from the window where the `pushbutton` is located. Just need a way to pass variables from both GUI windows.

Comment: You can always use `setappdata(groot, 'my_handles, handles)` and `handles = getappdata(groot, 'my_handles)`

Comment: That did it. Thanks a bunch, much appreciated! I have learnt so much from this.